# pandas read_csv issues/warning

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to read data from public dataset
https://www.kaggle.com/cityofLA/los-angeles-parking-citations#parking-citations.csv

my command:

```
parking_data=pd.read_csv("/datasets/parking-citations.csv",delimiter=',',dtype={'Issue Date' : str, 'Issue time':str, 'Marked Time': str, 'Plate Expiry Date':str})
```

and when i try to read the data into a pandas datfarame i get the below warning only when i make 'Marked Time': str in dtype.

warning

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (0,7) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

Can someone give me a reason why I am getting it?

It looks like `Marked Time` has some `NaN` values, but so does some of the other columns that I have given in dtype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your warning is coming from the zeroth column ('Ticket Number') and the 7th column ('VIN')

```
df = pd.read_csv('parking-citations.csv', dtype={'Ticket number':str, 'VIN':str})
```

So specifying the types of those columns fixes the issue.

Comment: thanks for reply.
can you please tell me how did you identified those are the culprit columns. 
as zero column ("ticket number") has non NaN values ....

Comment: You warning mentions the column numbers Columns (0,7)  and by looking at the dataFrame that is formed, you can check the name of those columns. Do mark the answer correct if it worked for you, Thanks.